# How does the energy consumption of the SHA-3 finalists compare?

Tags: hash, implementation, sha-3, sha-3-competition

I am curious, is there any paper where SHA-3 competitors are compared in terms of energy efficiency?

Comment: Table 4 of http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/hash2011/proceedings/hash2011_11.pdf has the energy consumption numbers for the finalists when implemented on an ASIC. It also has pointers for other papers when implemented on various other technologies.

Comment: I'm not sure this question fits well as stated. It definitely has some potential, however. Consider rewriting. Something that might be better would be, "Of the finalists in the SHA-3 competition, which is the most energy efficient?" or "How does the energy consumption of the SHA-3 finalists compare?"

Comment: Ok, I found the answer [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=QsUOEOSiy6cC&lpg=PA102&ots=NvBZX2knmp&dq=sha-3%20competitors%20comparison%20energy&pg=PA102#v=onepage&q=sha-3%20competitors%20comparison%20energy&f=false)

Comment: How can I close the question?

Comment: You can accept your own answer, although you'll need to wait some time before the software lets you do that.  However, for the benefit of others who may also be interested, it would be very nice if you could also summarize your findings briefly in your answer, instead of just giving a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the paper ["Comparison of the Power Consumption of the 2nd Round SHA-3 Candidates"](http://books.google.de/books?id=QsUOEOSiy6cC&lpg=PA102&ots=NvBZX2knmp&dq=sha-3%20competitors%20comparison%20energy&pg=PA102#v=onepage&q=sha-3%20competitors%20comparison%20energy&f=false) ([PDF version](http://www.beneficium.de/wp-content/publications/2010/wgk10.pdf)) by Benedikt Westermann, Danilo Gligoroski, and Svein Knapskog, published at the ICT Innovations 2010 Conference.